# Error when run heroku run php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I've deployed my laravel app to heroku, but when I try run `php artisan migrate` in heroku bash I get the following errors:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 4GrEPZThTu and table_name = migrations and table_type='BASE TABLE')

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I'm using remotemysql.com to host my database. I check all the DB configurations and it's all set correct. can anyone help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: Your config vars db in heroku are ok?

Comment: Yes all DB config in heroku are correct